# Content Provider vs SharedUserId vs Global Process for sharing data across applications

Tags: android, process, android-contentprovider

I found three ways to share data across applications.

1.**Content Provider**

2.**SharedUserId**-When you declare the same shared user id for more than one application, they can reach each other's resources (data fields, views, etc.). provided applications are signed with same certificate.

3.**Global Process**-Put a component of one application in separate process by using android:process attribute and naming process starting with lowercase letter and another component of another appication in separate process with same name as the separate process of first application.Now these components can share data.

**I am confused what to use when or which is more efficient?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found three ways to share data across applications.

#2 and #3 are the same, insofar as #3 (shared process) requires #2 (`sharedUserId`).

You also missed all other forms of standard Android IPC, including:

- starting activities
- starting services
- binding to services
- sending broadcasts

> I am confused what to use when

Ordinary app developers should use #1 (`ContentProvider`) or one of the other standard Android IPC mechanisms that I outlined above. You have no control over when users update apps, and using formal IPC enforces a clear separation between the apps, forcing you to think through things like API contracts, API versioning, and related concerns.

`sharedUserId` and shared processes are really there for device manufacturers, where apps are pre-installed and then updated in unison via a firmware update. Personally, I recommend to device manufacturers that they too use standard IPC, for most scenarios. For example, if App A modifies App B's files directly, how does App B find out? What if App B then overwrites App A's changes, because App B did not know about those changes? In many other areas of computer programming, we have gotten away from having multiple processes from multiple apps work with each others files directly.

> which is more efficient?

Efficiency should not be an issue in this case, as you should be using any of these techniques infrequently. If you have two apps that need to communicate with each other frequently, then you really have one app, and you should implement it that way.

Comment: Thanks.."You also missed all other forms of standard Android IPC".I guess activities through implicit intent and services through messenger for sharing data across applications. But these can be used for sharing only limited amount of data.You can't share complete database across applications through these approaches.I guess content provider is best way where you want to share large amount of structured data across different application?

Comment: "sharedUserId and shared processes are really there for device manufacturers, where apps are pre-installed and then updated in unison via a firmware update."..I am sorry but I am not able to understand what kind of apps are you talking about?Are you taking about apps which are already installed when we buy phone?How are they different from the other apps?

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma: "I guess content provider is best way where you want to share large amount of structured data across different application?" -- if the API that you want to expose looks like a database (query, insert, update, delete) or a stream, use a `ContentProvider`. If the API that you want to expose is custom, use a bound service. "Are you taking about apps which are already installed when we buy phone?" -- yes. "How are they different from the other apps?" -- they are under the control of the manufacturer and usually only get updated when the entire device is updated.

Comment: Thanks..Suppose I have created some apps and I want that if user login in any one of those apps then he should be signed in all the other apps in same device.What is better approach for doing this-using SharedUserId or AccountManager or ContentProvider?

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma: "What is better approach for doing this-using SharedUserId or AccountManager?" -- IMHO, the best answer is "don't have that feature". Of those two, `AccountManager` probably is the better solution. Be sure to allow support for users to have multiple accounts, though. Just because *you* think that users will want to use the same login information across all the apps does not mean that the *user* will want want to use the same login information.